# Why COCO evaluate with AP, AR by size? what are AR max =1, 10, 100's meaning

Tags: object-detection, evaluation

I'm reading [COCO Metrics](http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval) right now. And I have 2 questions about it.

This is the Metrics of COCO
[image]

1. I'm wondering why COCO evaluate AP and AR by size. What effect does image size have?
2. They measure AR by max which are 1, 10, 100. And they said AR max=1 is 'AR given 1 detection per image". Then, if model detect multiple objects per image, how to calculate AR? I can't understand the meaning of 'max'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because small objects are hard to detect for deeplearning detectors, so the detetctor who's AP small higher, is strongger at detect small object.
2. Per class base, caculate AR1
   https://github.com/rafaelpadilla/review_object_detection_metrics/blob/e4acc7ecab9a1e34110bad59e0c1e3d84ac7a127/src/evaluators/coco_evaluator.py#L306
   https://github.com/rafaelpadilla/review_object_detection_metrics/blob/e4acc7ecab9a1e34110bad59e0c1e3d84ac7a127/src/evaluators/coco_evaluator.py#L85